# How to install an application on OSX Mavericks more securely

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I would like to use multi factor authentication with PKCS type of token when to install application. Could you tell me, is there a way?

Current:
What I use to install an application securely is to use "only install Mac App Store". 
And, My worries are sometimes my home network is down cause of hacker and also no budget to implement such 802.1x solution. So, I would like to protect my Mac as much as I can. But if someone could know my password they might be get in my Mac remotely and install an application. Of course I have default firewall enabled.

Comment: Don't leave your Mac connected to the network when you're not using it... That could be your second factor. How often is your home network attacked that you need to have two-factor authentication to install applications?

Comment: I don't really use it but doesn't the App Store ask for a password anyway?

Comment: @Michael Frank, Thank you for your advice. I will do to unplug my PC when I leave my PC alone. I usually develop android application and search the information on Internet so I must connect to my home network. Regarding MFA, That's true your thoughts how often is key. But I would like to have the solution to keep safe.

Comment: @slhck, Yes, That's correct. But I would like to keep secure more cause of some suspicious matters.